# How to add custom fields to existing highcharts annotation

Tags: highcharts

How to bind custom fields to a highcharts annotation so that it appears in Edit popup as well as saves with annotation when chart is saved.
The following shows additional field appears in a line segment annotation. The additional field value can be saved along with annotation when user clicks on "save chart".

[image: additional field appear in Edit popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to wrap around the showForm function. You can add your custom fields and it will be save to annotation object.

```
    (function(H) {
      var PREFIX = 'highcharts-';
    
      H.wrap(H.Popup.prototype, 'showForm', function(proceed, type, chart, options, callback) {
        this.popup = chart.navigationBindings.popup;
    
        // show blank popup
        this.showPopup();
    
        // indicator form
        if (type === 'indicators') {
          console.log('This one creates indicators popup form');
          this.indicators.addForm.call(this, chart, options, callback);
        }
    
        // annotation small toolbar
        if (type === 'annotation-toolbar') {
          this.annotations.addToolbar.call(this, chart, options, callback);
        }
    
        // annotation edit form
        if (type === 'annotation-edit') {   
            //Here add custom fields in the edit form
            customFieldMap=new Object();
            customFieldMap.myField=['myField', 'text'];
            options.customFields=customFieldMap;    

            this.annotations.addForm.call(this, chart, options, callback);  
        }
    
        // flags form - add / edit
        if (type === 'flag') {
          this.annotations.addForm.call(this, chart, options, callback, true);
        }
      }}
    
    })(Highcharts);
```

Answer (score 1):

This requirement requires much more work than the regular Highcharts issue and looks like a custom project. I don't think that you will get a simple answer here or any other place. I can give you a guideline on where to start to dig into implementation.

First, you will need to get familiar with the function which creates a popup and do a wrap on it to add those input and logic to save it:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/Extensions/Annotations/Popup.ts

Wrap: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

And here you can find how the saved options are added to the annotation: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/Extensions/Annotations/NavigationBindings.ts